# Is the Poincaré dual of the first Stiefel-Whitney class of a manifold necessarily orientable?

Tags: algebraic-topology, characteristic-classes, non-orientable-surfaces

I think the answer should be yes, and I think there's an argument for it for triangulable (compact) manifolds as follows:

> For our $n$-manifold $M$, given a triangulation pick some $(n-1)$-simplices that give a submanifold (denoted $N$) dual to $[w_1(TM)]$. Then consider the barycentric subdivision of the entire triangulation. Away from the dual $N$, it will be possible to consistently label the $n$-simplices of $M$ as $+$ or $-$ depending on the orientation of the simplex. Since we have a barycentric subdivided triangulation, away from $N$ this labeling will label neighboring simplices by opposite signs. The border of where this opposite labeling fails is given by a set of $(n-1)$-simplices consisting of precisely $N$.
>
> So, $N$ can be thought of as consisting of the boundaries of $n$-simplices that both share the same $\pm$ sign. But, this means that the $(n-1)$-simplices that comprise $N$ can be given a consistent labeling of $+/-$ signs that come from the shared sign of the two $n$-simplices that share an $(n-1)$-simplex of $N$. These signs will alternate between neighboring $(n-1)$-simplices of $N$, and since we are considering a barycentric subdivided triangulation of $N$, this shows that $N$ is orientable

I'm wondering if there's also a characteristic class argument that would support this? Or if there's a counterexample that would invalidate the argument?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\require{AMScd}$

This is a nice qeustion with a nice answer. Your geometric proof looks reasonable though I did not check very hard. Here's an algebraic proof.

The point is that $w_1 \in H^1(\Bbb{RP}^\infty;\Bbb Z/2)$ admits a unique lift to $\tilde w_1 \in H^1(\Bbb{RP}^\infty; \Bbb Z_-)$, where $\Bbb Z_-$ is the nontrivial local system with fiber $\Bbb Z$ (this is a calculation). Now the Poincare duality map $H^1(M;\Bbb Z/2) \to H_{n-1}(M;\Bbb Z/2)$ fits into a commutative square with the Poincare duality map $H^1(M;\Bbb Z_{w_1}) \to H_{n-1}(M;\Bbb Z)$.

\begin{CD}
H^1(M;\Bbb Z_{w_1}) @>PD>> H_{n-1}(M;\Bbb Z) \\
@V\mod 2 VV @V\mod 2VV \\
H^1(M;\Bbb Z/2) @>PD>> H_{n-1}(M;\Bbb Z/2).
\end{CD}

The top-left term is cohomology with local system twisted by $w_1: \pi_1 M \to \pm 1$. Chasing $\tilde w_1$ both ways, we find that $PD(w_1) = PD(\tilde w_1) \pmod 2$, and so $PD(\tilde w_1)$ is the integral homology class / oriented cycle you're looking for.

In general if $R \to S$ is a homomorphism of coefficient systems, then Poincare duality (with suitably twisted coefficients) for $R$ and for $S$ fits into a commutative diagram as above.

Comment: Hi Jeff, thanks for the reply. I don't understand where $\mathbb{RP}^\infty$ comes into play here and what you mean by $\mathbb{Z}_-$. Does the square you drew somehow "factor through" $\mathbb{RP}^\infty$?

Comment: @Joe: 1) This uses the notion of cohomology with "twisted coefficients", which has input both an abelian group $A$ (here $\Bbb Z$) and a homomorphism $\pi_1(X) \to \text{Aut}(A)$ --- for $\Bbb Z_-$ I mean the isomorphism $\Bbb Z/2 \to \pm 1$; the minus sign is meant to indicate what we send $[1] \in \Bbb Z/2$ to. It is important to know what the maps $f: (X,x) \to (Y,y)$ induce in twisted cohomology --- it induces a map $H^*(Y;A_\rho) \to H^*(X;A_{f^*\rho})$, where $f^*\rho: \pi_1 X \to \text{Aut}(A)$ is the composite $\pi_1 X \to \pi_1 Y \to \text{Aut}(A)$.

Comment: The space $\Bbb{RP}^\infty$ is also known as $K(\Bbb Z/2,1)$; it has $H^1(\Bbb{RP}^\infty;\Bbb Z/2) = \Bbb Z/2$, with nonzero class named $w_1$. Every cohomology class $x \in H^1(X;\Bbb Z/2)$ arises as $f^*w_1$ for a map $f: \Bbb{RP}^\infty$. Now, since this class $w_1$ has a lift to a class $\tilde w_1 \in H^1(\Bbb{RP}^\infty;\Bbb Z_-)$, that means that every $x = f^*w_1$ also has a lift to $H^1(\Bbb{RP}^\infty; \Bbb Z_{f^*-})$, where the local system is the one induced by $\pi_1 X \to \Bbb Z/2$, the map $X \to \Bbb{RP}^\infty$ induces on $\pi_1$.

Comment: But under the bijection $H^1(X;\Bbb Z/2) \cong \text{Hom}(\pi_1 X, \Bbb Z/2)$, this means that the local coefficient system that $\tilde x$ lives in $H^1(X;-)$ of is what we would call $\Bbb Z_x$. Now the important part is the form of Poincare duality in non-oriented manifolds. It goes $H^1(M;A) \to H_{n-1}(M;A \otimes \Bbb Z_{w_1})$, where $A$ is a local coefficient system. This means that when we started from $\Bbb Z_{w_1}$, we end up at $\Bbb Z$. That's how this circle of ideas links back up to the diagram.